# Miele dishwasher making occasional whining noise

Tags: dishwasher, noise

Here's a video of the dishwasher making the noise while it's running: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rb33pgmhmxj3u731geu4h/2023-09-25-21.31.46.mp4?rlkey=ve5vhacfo16yst56sy15vddys&dl=0 (there's a leak detector sensor on the ground there).

It's a Miele Optima Series. The noise started occurring maybe 4 months ago or so, but hasn't necessarily gotten any better or worse.

---

I don't know if it's related, but we recently had some water/suds leaking out of the bottom of the dishwasher. We were using Puracy Dishwasher Pods for a while and I noticed that some people had leaking issues with it. We switched over to another brand and haven't had a leak since. The noise is still occurring though and didn't seem affected by the change.